# rotation matrix tranformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, tensors, rotations

Simple question that I'm banging my head against the desk with,

Let $S_{ij}$ be the symmetric part of some tensor $T_{ij}$. Trying to show $S_{ij}$ stays symmetric under O(3) rotations. Let $R_{ij}$ be some O(3)/rotation matrix.

$\begin{eqnarray*}
S_{ij}' &=& R_{ik}R_{jl}S_{lk} \\
&=& R_{ik}R_{jl}S_{kl} \\ 
&=& R_{jl}R_{ik}S_{kl} \\ 
&=& S_{ji}'
\end{eqnarray*}$

Can someone help me go from the 2nd to 3rd line? Why do the rotation matrices commute here?

Comment: You can view this as a relabeling $i \leftrightarrow j$, $k \leftrightarrow l$, follow up mg by using the symmetry of $S$. NB the proof does not depend on $R$ being orthogonal.

Comment: Also I might relabel $S_{lk}$ as $S_{kl}$ in the first line.

Comment: Wow. *Facepalm*. I can just skip the entire second step with your method. Ugh, so dumb. Thank you sir! :D

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful!